# Can attacker who is previous visitor to my home network put factory reset resistant spyware on my pc and phone from the WAN side?

Tags: network, spyware

I am amateur/barely novice to home networking trying to narrow down, if at all possible, angles of intrusion.

Attacker connects to home network after I willingly give password. Before they connect I:

- disconnect my pc (laptop Windows 10) from home network but leave my phone (Oneplus up-to-date android) connected for duration of their stay.
- I turn off access to administration for router (Huawei HG8145V5) from WAN side and LAN wifi side and change default ip for getting to administration login page to ip outside of range of "rented" ip addresses and put long powerful password
- unchecked all ips in router administration whitelist (probably remote assistance ips from isp since router was provided by them)

Attackers leaves and I factory reset the router (I restored same security settings) and my phone. Under these conditions is it still easy for the attacker from outside the network to put spyware that allows my monitor's contents to be seen ("system monitor" type of spyware?) on my pc and/or phone and that is resistant to factory resets of said pc and phone?

Comment: What is the reason that you think you have been hacked?

Comment: I only know because I get harassed on forums (new accounts with odd usernames that spill enough details of my life that I can recognize but not enough to incriminate) This is actually someone I grew up with and has been doing this for a while recently. They are a network administrator for a bank if that has anything to do with it. I know a lot mistakenly think they're hacked so I get it if you don't believe me. My only guess is could be physical access (they have keys to home) only 99% sure my devices physically secured. No hidden cameras either with line of sight. No idea how it's happening

Comment: I know this is crazy effort for someone to put. But long story short we had a massive falling out and I gave reason to harass like this. If you're wondering about why they have keys it's an ownership issue

Comment: Call the bank's fraud department. Tell them that you get harrassed, and that you think it's done by your previous friend X who is now a network administrator at the bank. That is if you're sure it's that person.

Answer (score 1):

> "is it still easy"

You have made it incredibly difficult, and it was not easy to begin with. It might still be *possible* if there was a specific vulnerability in the phone or router that allowed the attacker access. But it would have to be a very specific vulnerability to allow that.

> "all angles of intrusion"

What you have described is not the typical way attackers install backdoors into systems. In fact, it's more trouble than it's worth and not likely to succeed even if you had not done all the steps you outline.

If I wanted to install a backdoor onto someone's devices that I knew, I would simply send an email with an attachment saying, "hey, check this out".

"Hacking" doesn't happen the way it's shown in the movies. 99% of the time, it is social engineering ("click this!") or exploiting specific vulnerabilities that have not been patched.